# Issue installing icu4c 60 on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, homebrew, icu4c

I have an older Xserve that use as a development server and up to today brew has worked pretty well for keeping things up to date. I went to upgrade icu4c today though and got the following error.

Last 15 lines from /Users/mav2287/Library/Logs/Homebrew/icu4c/02.make:
13 errors generated.
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_ATOMIC=0 -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -I. -DDEFAULT_ICU_PLUGINS="/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/60.2/lib/icu"  -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT cstr.d cstr.o cstr.ao -o cstr.ao cstr.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------**
 Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_ATOMIC=0 -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -I. -DDEFAULT_ICU_PLUGINS="/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/60.2/lib/icu"  -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT charstr.d charstr.o charstr.ao -o charstr.ao charstr.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]:  **[cstr.ao] Error 1
make[1]:**  [charstr.ao] Error 1
13 errors generated.
 **Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_ATOMIC=0 -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -I. -DDEFAULT_ICU_PLUGINS="/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/60.2/lib/icu"  -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT udata.d udata.o udata.ao -o udata.ao udata.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [udata.ao] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 2

I am at a bit of a loss on this one and I'm not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone else runs in this the solution was to install GCC then use the  "brew install icu4c --cc=gcc-6" then it installed just fine.

Comment: If anyone else comes to this it's is important to mention the that Homebrew project doesn't focus much on the past version of OS X. MacPorts works about the same way and supports much further back and has an amazing team of people behind it making sure these things all install and run smoothly!

Comment: This works in OSX 10.12 where icu4c 67 brew install failed. I installed gcc@10 and uninstalled icu4c before running `brew install icu4c --cc=gcc-10` because option `--cc` apparently only works with `install`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @gemp thank you so much. You saved me. Though it spends 1 hour to compile gcc@10 at my macbook pro 2012. But it worths all efforts :)